# How to get "Open With" in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

In Windows 7 you could right-click a file and choose "Open With". In Windows 8 I don't see this option. Is there some way to get this in Windows 8?

**Edit:** Ack! I had "show file extensions" off (the default) and I had clicked into a zip file thinking it was a folder. Inside a zip file you never get those options.

Comment: My Windows 8 install still has that option. Could you post a screenshot of your right-click menu when clicking on a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really? It's still there for me?

[image]

Comment: You're correct. I had clicked into a zip file since I had file extensions turned off. I'll mark as answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Bryant - best form is to edit your specifics into this answer and keep the question uncomplicated with "edits" and updates. The system shows who edited what so you don't need meta information - just a cleanly worded Q & A.

Comment: Ha! Glad to hear you got it sorted :)